# How can I receive a signal that QNAM started downloading a web page in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I use Qt 5.7, C++ for my crawler. I've created timeout management based on the
[`NetworkTimeouts` class](https://github.com/leematos/weird-mixxx/blob/master/src/network.h), [implementation details (cpp)](https://github.com/leematos/weird-mixxx/blob/master/src/network.cpp).

I know that `QNetworkAccessManager`(QNAM) uses internal queue for URLs. How can I detect real download start and not just putting URL in the hidden queue? I call `QNetworkAccessManager::get()` in a loop (I don't wait for replyFinished() signal in order to push another URL). I need to start timer at the moment of real downloading. In Windows we have up to 6 parallel requests, others are waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QNetworkReply` for a `get()` request should start emitting `downloadProgress()` when it starts working.